# How to access XL-MS raw data and databases?

Tags: protein-protein-interaction

I'm looking for databases and/or raw data of protein mass spectrometry experiments.

After reviewing [xlinkdb](http://xlinkdb.gs.washington.edu/xlinkdb/) and [Proxl](https://proxl-ms.org/), I was curious to learn about other alternatives and options that allow users to run the database locally and browse raw experimental data. [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/?term=xl-ms) and [proteomexchange.org](http://proteomecentral.proteomexchange.org/cgi/GetDataset) don't seem to have enough data either.